# In Jquery UI using sortable and selectable. while sort an element it shows an id of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In  Jquery UI using sortable and selectable, i drag the element it shows the id of the dragged element using selectable.(using two field while i drag one element and to drop it in other .it shows the id of the dragged element)

Here is the html code.

```
<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>  
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">  
    <li ><img src="./images/tirein.png"><span>tier 1</span></li>
    <li><img src="./images/tirein.png"><span>tier 2</span></li>
    <li><img src="./images/tirein.png"><span>tier 3</span></li>
</ul>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
</ul>
```

here is the Jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1a, #sortable2a" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    });

    $("#sortable1, #sortable2" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#sortable1 li" ).index( this );
                 result.append("image" + ( index + 1 )+ " has moved"  );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the question?